# Angular-Formly: Reset Field Model When Hidden

Tags: angular-formly

Using Angular Formly, I am using 'hideExpression' to hide a field based on another field's model value. This works as expected. However, I need to reset the hidden fields model value when it becomes hidden.  How can this be accomplished in Angular-Formly? Is there some type of event I can hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use hideExpression callback and set model value before return true or false

```
{
            key: 'model_key',
            type: 'input',
            templateOptions: {
                label: 'Your label'
            },
            hideExpression: function ($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
                var hide = true; // replace true with your condition
                if (hide) {
                     vm.model.model_key = '';
                }
                return hide;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Zohaib, if you read this (1 year and two months later). Can you tell me please; i replace true with the condition. Let's say like in this bin http://jsbin.com/tifizogizu/1/edit?js,output ; but it's not functioning like i expected, can you help me?

Comment: If you want to use expression then don't use function.

Comment: @LexHartman use `hideExpression: "!model.name"` and if you want to use function then return truthy value to hide.

Comment: use "hideExpression" instead of hideExpression.

Answer (score 0):

In the link to the JS Bin use the scope instead, something like

```
hideExpression: function ($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
  var hide = !scope.model.name;
  if (hide) {
    vm.model.iLikeTwix = false;
  }
  return hide;
}
```